# Limit Apache2.4 Request Headers

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I'm trying to limit a virtual host's request headers to only `POST`, `HEAD` and `GET`. What I've done so far is I created a `.htaccess` for my virtual host and typed in the following:

```
<LimitExcept GET HEAD POST>
    Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

The problem is `<LimitExcept>` shows an error that says `not allowed here`, so I tried using `<Limit>` but it results to the same error. I've also tried moving them inside my virtual host `.conf` file and it still an error. What I don't  understand is that in the official docs it says  that it allowed there and yet in my server it's not.

Comment: you can't configure inside virtualhost?

Comment: @ezra-s, I can configure my virtualhost

Comment: then see my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to allow only GET, POST and HEAD methods, then this should work just fine:

```
<Directory "/path/to/documentroot">
    Require method GET POST HEAD
</Directory>
```

You'll need to put this configuration within your VirtualHost.

**EDIT:**
And to answer your other question in the comment (how to enable password authentication for POST requests only), this can be achieved with the following directives (that you can put in /path/to/your/directory/.htaccess):

```
<RequireAny>
     AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
     AuthName "Login"
     AuthType Basic
     Require method GET HEAD
     Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

This will allow GET and HEAD methods, but POST requests trigger authentication.

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. Follow up  question though, how do I put authentication for POST requests?

Comment: @Helquin mark the answer that solved your problem

Comment: @Helquin I edited my answer to include the answer for your question about POST requests. Like c4f4t0r said, don't forget to mark the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

2.4 has a specific module for this, called mod_allowmethods, and Limit/LimitExcept usage is discouraged in 2.4. Make sure you load the module and in the appropiate virtualhost add this:

```
# documentroot dir in virtualhost
<Directory /path/to/dir>
     AllowMethods GET HEAD POST
     Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

You can also make it global defining it earlier in server config to everything like I describe bellow.

***note this is / in your filesystem so you should deny access here and allow in specific directories like documentroot or aliased ones afterwards, but allowmethods propagate further down unless you override it later.

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
    AllowMethods GET HEAD POST
</Directory>
```